# Running a Cron job daily from 6 am to 11:30 pm

Tags: cron, job-scheduling

Could you help me please to run my cron job daily 
 from 6 am to 11:30 pm in the following format

- - - - - command path

Thanks

Comment: For some reason this was the top result for "crontab run until midnight" in google for me, so I'll add the answer for that here too, to run every minute from 6am until midnight you can't use `* 6-0 * * *`, it won't throw any errors and won't run, use `* 0,6-23 * * *` instead

Comment: */3 06-23 * * 1-5 my-command This can help http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples

Answer (score 18, accepted):

cron can start jobs easily enough, but if you need to run something *from* 6am to 11.30pm, you'll need to issue a start command at 6am, and a stop command at 11.30pm.

something like this:

```
## start the job (6am)
  0  6 * * * /usr/bin/start-my-job

## stop the job (11.30pm)
 30 23 * * * /usr/bin/stop-my-job
```

edit:  i think i see what you're asking for now.  try this:

```
## every three minutes between 6am and 11.30pm
    */3  6-22 * * * my-command
 0-30/3    23 * * * my-command
```

edit:  okay, if you want 6pm until midday the following day, you need:

```
## every three minutes between midnight and midday
  */3   0-11  * * * my-command
## every three minutes between 6pm and midnight
  */3  18-23  * * * my-command
```

Comment: i have written the following but giving bad hour when i try to save in cron tab .
I have written
*/3 19-12 * * * mycommand path

Comment: I want in a single command not two separate command

Comment: that's not how cron works.  you can simply kill the process at 11.30pm, if you like, but there is no way to tell cron to run a command for a specified period of time.  if you think about it, it doesn't really make sense.

Comment: every 3 minutes is working fine thats why i am not asking about the miniut. My problem in hour. As my cron should run daily from 7 pm to 11:30 am or 12 am in US time. Clear?

Comment: ah - i think i see what you're asking for

Comment: */3 19-12 * * * 
where is the error even following also giving error
*/3 19-12 * * mon-sat 
if i want to run my cron only in development working day (monday to saturday)

Comment: i think we're on the same page now -- see edits :)

Comment: */3  6-23 * * * my-command, its good but if i want evening 6pm to day 12 am then will it be */3  18-12 * * * my-command ?

Comment: 12am is midnight.  do you mean midnight or midday (12pm)?

Comment: ## every three minutes between 6pm and midnight
  */3   6-23  * * * my-command

The first one "## every three minutes between midnight and midday" is correct but this one "## every three minutes between 6pm and midnight"  should be  */3   16-23  * * * my-command 

Just confirm me Simon

Comment: it should be 18 (6pm) :)

Comment: ah! yes , it shout be 18
Thank you very much for giving me clue. Thank you boss. You save my time. :)